# Sites 9 Upgrade from Web 8.1.0

Tags: web8, upgrade, sites-9

We are currently using SDL Web 8.1.0. Now, we are planning to Upgrade to Tridion Sites 9. Going through the documentations we understand that we cannot upgrade directly to Sites 9 from Web 8.1.0. We need to Either upgrade to 8.1.1 or 8.5 before proceeding with Sites 9 upgrade. We are considering 8.1.1 cumulative update.

But, the servers where current CM and CD are hosted do not match with Hardware and Software requirement for Sites 9. So, We guess we need to do fresh installation of Sites 9 in new servers matching prerequisites. In this scenario do we need to still go with 8.1.1 cumulative update? If we do new installation of Sites 9 and migrate CM and CD Data from old instances to new instances will work?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're asking two questions.

> Do we need to apply the cumulative update

**Yes**. It clearly states (on the link provide by Atila) that you can upgrade from SDL Web 8 *"with Cumulative Update 1 applied"*. I'd suggest it probably makes sense to apply the cumulative update anyway - it's likely you're simply working around a few problems (or even unaware of them) currently.

> {do} we need to do fresh installation of Sites 9 in new servers matching prerequisites

**You don't *have* to** but if you have the opportunity it's likely much cleaner.

- Trying to upgrade your infrastructure in-situ will present a number of possible complications (if technically feasible - depending on your old/to/new versions); will you break 8.1, how long can you be offline
- If you have the opportunity then you could stand-up a new environment and bring across the upgraded database etc., here you have a plethora of options but you'll be working in two environments trying to keep content aligned along with publishing etc. (beware the workflow too)

> In this scenario do we need to still go with 8.1.1

**Yes**. If you're wanting to upgrade from 8, then per the documentation you need the hotfix.

Depending on your timelines, budget and risk adversity, I would certainly consider upgrading to 8.5 and taking advantage of the *rolling upgrades*. Of course, it depends on any many factors. If you've a lone CM with a simple CD you've a different set of considerations/constraints than an organisation with scaled out CMs and scaled out CDs with a mass of GUI/other extensions and Workflow and Translation in the mix.

Answer (score 3):

If you are provisioning new app servers from scratch, then upgrade of the app servers is obviously not applicable.

However, you will have to upgrade your DBs to 8.1.1 first to ensure your uograde to 9.0 is supported (the direct upgrade path has simply not been tested by SDL).

Furthermore, it makes sense to upgrade at least one app server to 8.1.1 too, to verify that the pre-upgraded DB still works properly.

This staged approach makes it easier to analyze upgrade issues, if any. If you face upgrade issues after a direct upgrade from 8.1.0, don’t expect a lot of support from SDL. However upgrades from 8.1.0 to 8.1.1 and from 8.1.1 to 9.0 are fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you **can** upgrade from 8.1 See the list of available version from which you can upgrade to Sites 9 [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C&addHistory=true&filename=GUID-1F731D78-813C-4700-9B60-362CB77A13EC.xml&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C).
What you cannot do from that version is a "direct" rolling upgrade to Sites 9. Those are supported starting Web 8.5.

But if you have any doubts, you can always check with SDL support.

Comment: yes i have referred this document and we do not have SDL Web 8 with cumulative update 1 applied. so my question is do i need this cumulative update?